# Why does Stackdriver combine multiple messages?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a GAE app writing to stdout using print() in Python. Stackdriver picks it up and correctly interprets the output as JSON payloads mostly fine, except for a few thousand in every batch of about thirty thousand messages where it actually combines multiple JSON objects into a single log entry and interprets it as a text payload - and I'd like it to not do that.

I'm stumped because I've even moved the print() to a separate thread and introduced time delays between each print() so I don't believe there's a reason for this to happen. I've also searched endlessly to find someone experiencing the same issue but that didn't turn up anything.

Here's the code - `write()` takes a single messag that gets published to a PubSub topic:

```
def write(self, input):

    self.future = self.publisher.publish(self.topic_name, input)
    self.future.add_done_callback(self.callback)
    log_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.log_message, kwargs={"input": input})
    log_thread.start()

def log_message(self, input):
    event = json.loads(input.decode("utf-8"))
    event['topic'] = self.topic_name # the pubsub topic address
    event['publish_time'] = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(payload)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Expected log output to stackdriver is:

```
{"unique_event_id": "x", "hashed_msisdn": "x", "event_timestamp": 1600449466477041, "event_name": "random_event", "topic": "projects/x/topics/y", "publish_time": "2020-09-21 17:32:09"}
```

Instead what I get (sometimes) is 2 or 3 events grouped together in a single log line interpreted as text:

```
{"unique_event_id": "x_event_1", "hashed_msisdn": "x", "event_timestamp": 1600449466477041, "event_name": "random_event", "topic": "projects/x/topics/y", "publish_time": "2020-09-21 17:32:09"}{"unique_event_id": "x_event_2", "hashed_msisdn": "x", "event_timestamp": 1600449466477123, "event_name": "some_other_random_event", "topic": "projects/x/topics/z", "publish_time": "2020-09-21 17:32:09"}
```

The only pattern I can see is that the publish time (determined by `datetime.utcnow()`) is the same for these clusters of events.

I'd really appreciate some insight / guidance here. Thanks!

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that this happens even without the separate thread and time delay? What his the rate of requests when this happens?

Comment: Do the log messages come from the same instance ID or from different  instances? Could you try including the instance ID in the output?

Comment: Yeah, this happens regardless of threading. The log messages are coming from a mix of different and the same instances - separate cron jobs calling the same service (and I usually have 2-4 instances active). I'll add the instance ID in and see what turns up. Thanks!